# Using If statment

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use an If/else statement in bash. I'm confused which is the correct syntax.

```
  if [ "$NUMBER_dcn" -gt $NO ]
  then
  dir_dcn='/mnt/md0/capture'
  fi
```

or

```
   if [ "{$NUMBER_dcn}" -gt $NO ]
  then
  dir_dcn='/mnt/md0/capture'
  fi
```

NUMBER_dcn is populated using

```
NUMBER_dcn=$(find /mnt/md0/capture/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pcap" |wc -l)
```

Are both of them correct because one of them is giving me an "integer expression expected"
error.

Comment: The second one should not be `${NUMBER_dcn}` instead?

Comment: That was a typo. :)

Comment: Ok :p Anyways why are you putting your variables into double quotes? As you are using `-gt`, it should be a number. Can you try without the quotes?

Comment: I've tested it, iwth and without quotes and with boths writings with no issue. Are you sure $NO contains a number? How is it populated? Are you using bash, or else?

Comment: Yes NO=0 and I'm using bash

Comment: You can run the script with `bash -x <script name>` to debug it. It will print the content of variables for instance. Or by adding `#!/bin/bash -x` as first line in the script.

Comment: @Jishnu U Nair: just to understand, was the typo you corrected just in the writting of the question on the site or also present in your script ? Because if it was also present in your script and you corrected it you have certainly explained and solved your problem.

Comment: @Benoit, the typo happend when I was writing the question.

Comment: It looks like you edited the question to remove the bug. And now your question makes no sense, since neither version would produce the error you're asking about.

Comment: Reverted your last edit so at least it's consistent.

Comment: You must copy and paste your code in here correctly, and accept your mistakes not hide them, 3 people have already tried to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of referencing a variable is `$VAR`. Since your `VAR` is populated by `wc`, I'm assuming that it is always non-empty, so you don't actually need the quotes `""` - those are only for guarding against the case that a variable might be totally empty.

However, that is not your problem here. The `-gt` operator not only requires two arguments, but they must be integers. What you're passing to `-gt` here is, e.g. `50` in the one case and `{50}` in the other. The latter is not an integer expression, it's a String starting with `{`, so you should leave the braces off.

Braces are a permissible alternative syntax for using variables: `$VAR` is the same as `${VAR}`. This is sometimes useful when you *interpolate* a variable in a way that it is unclear where the variable name ends. For instance, if you want to print your variable value and an index, sometimes it is necessary to write something like

```
echo ${VAR}00
```

to get output like `Hugo00`. Without the braces, bash would try to dereference the variable `VAR00` and fail, since there is no such variable. (Note that in this case there is a dollar sign in front of the braces.) But since you're not interpolating anything, but using the variable exactly as it is, you don't need to bother with braces.

Comment: So what you say is when the variable contains only numbers, `$VAR` and `${VAR}` do not behave the same ? If you look at the question, the second form of the OP's script is `${NUMBER_dcn}`, the `$` is placed before the curly brace. See the edit of the question by the OP.

Comment: No, the *content* of the variable is irrelevant. Braces are useful to influence the behaviour of bash during the *parsing* state before dereferencing. They make a difference only when the dereferencing expression is written immediately before another character that *could* be part of the variable name, but isn't. For instance, a fake Russian generator might use something like `for word in $SENTENCE; do echo -n "${word}ski "; done`.

Comment: I just wanted to attract your attention on the fact that the question as been edited to contain "${NUMBER_dcn}" and no more "{$NUMBER_dcn}" which would indeed produce the effect you described in your answer.